# Tiles generation not yielding results inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, openstreetmap, geojson, path-finding

I'm trying to create a local instance of an open-source project called [Accessmaps](https://github.com/AccessMap/accessmap). To summarize it, it's a map that help people with movement disabilities find the shortest paths in cities that don't block their way.

The app uses the Overpass API to fetch the necessary map data in **.geojson** file format so that it can be displayed on [Webapp](https://github.com/AccessMap/accessmap-webapp).

There's two type of .geojson files that the app uses:

- The **regions.geojson** which is used for the City information, to zoom the user to the location of the city and to outline the borders of the city.
- The **transportation.geojson** which is the street network of the city. This is what the Webapp uses to display the available sidewalks and crossing on the map and what the pathfinding engine uses to give the shortest routes.

It should be noted that the transportaion.geojson needs to follow this [schema](https://github.com/OpenSidewalks/OpenSidewalks-Schema)

The pathfinding engine that's used is called [Unweaver](https://github.com/nbolten/unweaver)

The app runs in **three** **Docker containers**:

1. Webapp (build_webapp)
2. Tiles (build_tiles)
3. Unweaver (build_unweaver)

My issue now is that when the app is running, when I select two points on the map for Unweaver to give me the shortest route, I get the errors seen in this image: [Errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxYvM.png)

From the looks of it, the tiles are not building correctly and I don't know why.

First thing that I tried was to change the way my transportation.geojson is structed. I've tried multiple ways but I always seem to get the same errors.

I tried looking into how the tiles are generated and where they are located inside the Docker container, but I'm new and still learning how to use docker so that was a dead end for me.

The data_fetchers I used and the .geojson can be found in [this repo](https://github.com/Futsies/OSM-data-fetchers)

More changes that I've done to the repos that I'm using can also be found on [this repo](https://github.com/AccessMapsCorfu)

I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light into my case. Please ask for anything else that needs to be mentioned and has slipped my mind.

**The reason I'm not seeking help from the creator of the project is because he doesn't work on the project anymore and is not willing to provide help**